# Tour of Go exercise #23: rot13Reader

Tags: go

I'm trying to solve the Tour of Go exercise [rot13Reader](https://tour.golang.org/methods/23):

Here is my solution:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func rot13(x byte) byte {
    switch {
    case x >= 65 && x <= 77:
        fallthrough
    case x >= 97 && x <= 109:
        x = x + 13
    case x >= 78 && x <= 90:
        fallthrough
    case x >= 110 && x >= 122:
        x = x - 13
    }
    return x
}

func (r13 *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r13.r.Read(b)
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
        b[i] = rot13(b[i])
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

It returns `You prnpxrq tur poqr!`, that means only the first word of "Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!" is cracked. How can I crack the whole sentence?

Comment: answers: https://gist.github.com/inancgumus/d25d045b4cec43dcbb111e04980d396b

Comment: Can someone explain why the first line of the Read function needs to assign somewhere? I use a for range to loop through the byte array, and then try to return len(b), nil but it gives me a timeout error. I'm still doing r13.r.Read(b), just not assigning it anywhere. Confused what the difference is.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Basically your solution is good and works, you just mistyped 1 character:

```
case x >= 110 && x >= 122:
```

Change it to:

```
case x >= 110 && x <= 122:
```

---

Your input and output:

```
Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!
You prnpxrq tur poqr!
```

There is change in every word. The problem is not that only the first word is read and decoded, the problem is in your decoding algorithm.

In [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) if shifting goes outside of the letter range, you have to start from the beginning of the alphabet (or at the end). For example shifting `'N'` would be `'Z'` + 1, so it becomes `'A'`, the first letter. See this simple character mapping:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
```

So what you should do is after shifting by 13, if the letter goes outside of the alphabet, shift it by `-26` (number of letters in the English alphabet) which has the desired effect (that after the last letter you continued from the first).

An example solution:

```
func rot13(x byte) byte {
    capital := x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z'
    if !capital && (x < 'a' || x > 'z') {
        return x // Not a letter
    }

    x += 13
    if capital && x > 'Z' || !capital && x > 'z' {
        x -= 26
    }
    return x
}
```

And its output:

```
You cracked the code!
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/sb1vtLP1Dx).

Answer (score 9):

You could also use instead:

```
func rot13(x byte) byte {
    input := []byte("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    output := []byte("NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm")
    match := bytes.Index(input, []byte{x})
    if match == -1 {
        return x
    }
    return output[match]
}
```

Comment: This is cool, but should probably be implemented with a map due to the time complexity of seeking through the input list. It's still going to be more efficient to just calculate the value though, and efficiency matters if you are applying rot13 to huge byte streams.

Answer (score 4):

```
func (reader rot13Reader) Read(bytes []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := reader.r.Read(bytes)
    for i, val := range bytes[:n] {
        if val >= 'a' && val <= 'z' {
            bytes[i] = (val-'a'+13)%26 + 'a'
        } else if val >= 'A' && val <= 'Z' {
            bytes[i] = (val-'A'+13)%26 + 'A'
        }
    }
    return n, err
}
```

Comment: Simply providing code as an answer is not very helpful, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: No need to be so critical here. People having fun posting their solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer manipulate directly integers in rot13 function

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

const a int = int('a')
const z int = int('z')

const A int = int('A')
const Z int = int('Z')

func rot13(b int) int {

    isLower := b >= a && b <= z
    isUpper := b >= A && b <= Z

    if isLower {
        return a + ((b - a + 13) % 26)
    }

    if isUpper {
        return A + ((b - A + 13) % 26)
    }

    return b
}

func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := rot.r.Read(b)
    if err == io.EOF {
        return 0, err
    }

    for x := range b {
        b[x] = byte(rot13(int(b[x])))
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function does not work as you want. To verify this, just try to run your function on `"Lbh penpxrq Lbh gur pbqr!"`. As you see first word is decoded (as well as the third one). So this means that your function does not run only on the first word, but in fact runs on all the words (it just happened that nothing else is changed).

```
func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = rot.r.Read(p)
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        if (p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] < 'N') || (p[i] >='a' && p[i] < 'n') {
            p[i] += 13
        } else if (p[i] > 'M' && p[i] <= 'Z') || (p[i] > 'm' && p[i] <= 'z'){
            p[i] -= 13
        }
    }
    return
}
```

And here is a <kbd>[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pNsZVvAsbU)</kbd>. Code is taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/zyxar/2317744).

Answer (score 2):

My code also works, it's more simple!

```
func (rd *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    m := make(map[byte]byte)
    input := "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    output := "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
    for idx := range input {
        m[input[idx]] = output[idx]
    }

    n, err := rd.r.Read(b)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if val, ok := m[b[i]]; ok {
          b[i] = val
        }
    }
    return n, err
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := rot.r.Read(b)
    if err == io.EOF {
        return 0, err
    }

    for i := range b {
        var base byte
        if b[i] >= 'a' && b[i] <= 'z' {
            base = 'a'
        } else if b[i] >= 'A' && b[i] <= 'Z' {
            base = 'A'
        } else {
            continue
        }
        b[i] = (((b[i] - base) + 13) % 26) + base
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to the answer by @icza, rather than hard-coding the checks for whether the byte is alphabetic or not, create a small function to determine it instead. It makes for much cleaner code.

```
func alphabetic(x byte) bool {
    return (x >= 'A' && x <='Z') || (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
}

func capital(x byte) bool {
    return x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z'
}

func rot13(x byte) byte {
    // byte isn't a letter
    if !alphabetic(x) {
        return x
    }

    original_is_capital := capital(x)

    // apply rot13  
    x += 13

    // the new letter should loop around
    if !alphabetic(x) || original_is_capital {
        x -= 26
    }

    return x
}
```

Comment: I think it will mess up, as adding 13 to 'Z' will result in 'g' which will be still 'alphabetic', but not what you expect (which should be 'M')

Comment: That's pretty funny - the test on the Golang page counted it as correct because it didn't test capital letters very much. I have updated it on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Z8lLtKYkNz)

Answer (score 1):

```
func rot13(x byte) byte {
    if (x >=  'A' && x <= 'M') || (x >=  'a' && x <= 'm') {
        return x + 13
    } else if (x >=  'N' && x <= 'Z') || (x >=  'n' && x <= 'z') {
        return x - 13
    } else {
        return x
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My try:

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const a byte = byte('a')
const n byte = byte('n')
const z byte = byte('z')

const A byte = byte('A')
const N byte = byte('N')
const Z byte = byte('Z')


type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func rot13(b byte) byte {
    switch {
        case ((b >= A && b < N) || (b >= a && b < n)):
            b += 13
        case ((b >= N && b <= Z) || (b >= n && b <= z)):
            b -= 13
    }
    return b
}

func (r13 rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r13.r.Read(b)
    
    for x := range b[:n] {
        b[x] = rot13(b[x])
    }
    
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

A simple and intuitive approach :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple code snippet that changes alphabets and ignores other characters

```
func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(b [] byte) (int, error) {
    size,e := rot.r.Read(b)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        if b[i] < byte('A') || b[i] > byte('z') {
            continue
        }
        if b[i] > byte('a') {
            b[i] = byte('a') + (b[i] - byte('a') + 13)%26
        } else {
            b[i] = byte('A') + (b[i] - byte('A') + 13)%26
        }
    }
    return size, e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my 2 cents in as well:

https://play.golang.org/p/1Wze47kL-bA

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (r rot13Reader) Read(buf []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.r.Read(buf)

    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        r := rune(buf[i])
        if !unicode.IsLetter(r) {
            continue
        }
        isUpper := unicode.IsUpper(r)
        r += 13
        if !unicode.IsLetter(r) || isUpper && r >= 'a' {
            r -= 26
        }
        buf[i] = byte(r)
    }
    return n, err
}

func ExampleRot13Reader() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
    // Output: You cracked the code!
}
```

Preparing for comments such as "Simply providing code as an answer is not very helpful"... this is a special case where the questioner is asking for other solutions, and this is a fun way to compare various approaches. No need to really explain much.

Comment: Hi mh-cbon. You didn't copy my code in correctly. This is what I see in your playground. Not the same as above:
```
func (r13 *zephaniaRot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
 size, e := r13.r.Read(b)
 for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
  if b[i] < byte('A') || b[i] > byte('z') {
   continue
  }
  if b[i] > byte('a') {
   b[i] = byte('a') + (b[i]-byte('a')+13)%26
  } else {
   b[i] = byte('A') + (b[i]-byte('A')+13)%26
  }
 }
 return size, e

}
```

Comment: For example notice that the playground version has no call to `unicode.IsUpper()`

Comment: By the way, this is fun. I'm not sure we're following the typical Stack Overflow best practices, but why stop when you're having fun.

Comment: indeed, sorry for that mistake of mine. Although, fun is one thing, but this post need some care with all those various methods. I have updated the playground https://play.golang.org/p/HGqOFuzIgmu

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you neither want to use maps nor those fancy-schmancy functions/operators other folks are using, you can set up an array-based translation table that needs no searching. Trick it to have all the rot13-ing be done ahead of time by using an array of bytes where the index has the rot-13'd value.

Note that the translation array is programmatically generated as an example, and frankly, the code is easier to read / crosscheck than:

```
x = [256]byte{0, 1, 2,..., (lower rot13 values), ..., (upper...), ...,255}
```

Code as below

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
    r13array [256]byte
}

// Don't forget the *, or it will do all the work on a copy and throw
// it away
func (r *rot13Reader) initialize_r13() {
    // Must be called before doing any rot-13-ing
    var cap_A_offset int = int('A')
    var low_a_offset int = int('a')

    // For simplicity's sake, initialize the entire array, index=itself
    for c := 0; c < 256; c++ {
        r.r13array[c] = byte(c)
    }

    // Now pre-calculate the rot-13 values for A-Z and a-z
    // These will override the value in the array
    for c := 0; c <= 26; c++ {
        rot_13 := (c + 13) % 26
        r.r13array[c + cap_A_offset] = byte(rot_13 + cap_A_offset)
        r.r13array[c + low_a_offset] = byte(rot_13 + low_a_offset)
    }
}

func (r rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    numread, e := r.r.Read(b)
    if e == nil {
        for i := 0; i < numread; i+= 1 {
            c := r.r13array[b[i]]
            // Just not worth doing something like "if in != out"
            // before setting...I suspect that might even be slower.
            b[i] = c
        }
    }
    return numread, e   
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s, [256]byte{}}
    r.initialize_r13()
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your approach makes it easy to commit a typo as you have 8 comparisons. Also, you use integer values (`97`) instead of literal runes (`'a'`).

That being said, you could use some [code to precalculate a LUT](https://play.golang.com/p/pth-PcetYEO) that you can then use as a constant. The validation is then reduced to the limits of where you want to index such LUT.

```
import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

const lut = "                                 " + 
            "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@" +
            "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM[\\]^_`" + 
            "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm{|}~"

func (r13 *rot13Reader) Read(out []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r13.r.Read(out)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        r := out[i]
        if r > 31 && r < 127 {
            out[i] = lut[r]
        }
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I solved it:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func rot13(r byte) byte {
    sb := rune(r)
    if sb >= 'a' && sb <= 'm' || sb >= 'A' && sb <= 'M' {
        sb = sb + 13
    }else if sb >= 'n' && sb <= 'z' || sb >= 'N' && sb <= 'Z' {
        sb = sb - 13
    }
    return byte(sb)

}

func (r13 *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (i int, e error) {
    n, err := r13.r.Read(b)
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
        b[i] = rot13(b[i])
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are my two cents:

(Note that 'Z' ASCII code is 90 and 'h' is 114)

```
func (r rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = r.r.Read(p)
    if err == nil {
        for i := range p {
            if c := p[i] + 13; c > 'z' || (c > 'Z' && c < 'h') {
                p[i] = c - 26
            } else {
                p[i] = c
            }
        }
    }
    return n, err
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My Try:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    io.Reader
}

func (r rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, _ = r.Reader.Read(p)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if p[i] != byte(' ') {
            if p[i] > byte('m') {
                p[i] = p[i] - 13
            } else {
                p[i] = p[i] + 13
            }
        }
    }
    err = io.EOF
    return
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    _, _ = io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Comment: Why the negative feedback?

Answer (score -1):

My solution was this:

```
func rot13(b byte) byte {
    in := []byte("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    out := []byte("NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm")

    for i, v := range in {
        if v == b {
            return out[i]
        }
    }

    return b
}

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := rot.r.Read(b)

    for i := range b {
        b[i] = rot13(b[i])
    }

    return n, err
}
```

Answer (score -2):

two years has already passed since the question asked, but I want to share my code which was very simple compared to.

```
func (rot rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = rot.r.Read(p)  // read the string into byte array, n holds the length
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        upper := p[i] >='A'||p[i]<='Z' //new
        lower := p[i]>='a'||p[i]<='z'  //new
        if (upper||lower){ //new
            p[i] += 13   // we are simply decoding here
            if (upper && p[i] > 'Z') || (lower && p[i] > 'z') { //new
                p[i] -= 26 // and semi-circle the table if it goes beyond
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

the result? `You cracked the code.` Of course it would be better to implement all ascii scale, but it still does most of the job.

---

**EDIT**: After a year and a half, a bugged edit by someone else, and a critic about that bug led me to edit this post. The edit still keeps the simplicity of the code while providing few extra conditionals. Moreover, one can turn this code into a rot13 encoder easily. Previous output was `You-cracked-the-code.`

Comment: I think this is the best one, unless anyone need to reuse rot13 logic.

Comment: This fails for input between >`Z` and <`a` (e.g. for characters like "_"). (It also doesn't compile, presumably `b` should be `p`).

Comment: @DaveC, from the closing sentence of the post, you could yourself tell it does not work for the interval you mentioned. and for the compiling, yep, the last editor user did that mistake trying to implement and interval. now that you brought this to my attention, i can implement "alphabet only" condition, yet still it preserves it elegance

Comment: This is good approach but code is incorrect.  The `||` should be replaced with `&&` when defining `lower` and `upper`.